# How do I update a JPanel with information from a different class?

Tags: java, jpanel, listselectionlistener

I created the following example source and am wondering what I need to do to update my JPanel with a JLabel that has the information located from the row clicked in the JTable.

I also wanted to note that this is just a bare example as I've improved the sample code quite a bit thanks to a few SO members here. So I'm posting this bare example as a way to learn

SwingTesting (main)

```
public class SwingTesting {

    private final JFrame frame;
    private final TablePane tablePane;
    private final JSplitPane splitPane;
    private final JPanel infoPanel;
    private final JLabel infoLabel;

    public SwingTesting() {
        tablePane = new TablePane();
        infoPanel = new JPanel();
        frame = new JFrame();

        infoLabel = new JLabel();    //this is the panel i want to add the label to
        infoPanel.add(infoLabel);

        splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, tablePane, infoPanel);

        frame.add(splitPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SwingTesting();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

TablePane

```
public class TablePane extends JPanel {

    private final JTable table;
    private final TableModel tableModel;
    private final ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel;

    public TablePane() {
        table = new JTable();
        tableModel = createTableModel();
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        table.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true); 

        listSelectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
        table.setSelectionModel(listSelectionModel);
        listSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new SharedListSelectionHandler());
        table.setSelectionModel(listSelectionModel);

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.ipadx = 2;
        gbc.ipady = 2;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;

        this.add(new JScrollPane(table), gbc);
    }

    private TableModel createTableModel() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[] {"Car", "Color", "Year"}, 0 
        ){
            @Override public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        addTableData(model);
        return model;
    }

    private void addTableData(DefaultTableModel model) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] {"Nissan", "Black", "2007"});
        model.addRow(new Object[] {"Toyota", "Blue", "2012"});
        model.addRow(new Object[] {"Chevrolet", "Red", "2009"});
        model.addRow(new Object[] {"Scion", "Silver", "2005"});
        model.addRow(new Object[] {"Cadilac", "Grey", "2001"});
    }


    class SharedListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {

        //When selection changes i want to add a label to the panel
        //currently it just prints out the info from the selected row    
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();
            String contents = "";

            if(lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("<none>");
            } else {
                int minIndex = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
                int maxIndex = lsm.getMaxSelectionIndex();
                for(int i = minIndex; i <= maxIndex; i++) {
                    if(lsm.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                        for(int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                            contents += table.getValueAt(i, j) + " ";
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(contents);
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering how to access that JPanel from the ListSelectionListener. Should I just pass the panel to the TablePane class? Or is there a more proper way to do this?

Also, my ListSelectionListener prints out the row information twice for some reason, did I mess up the loop?

**EDIT**

```
public class TablePane extends JPanel {

    private final JTable table;
    private final TableModel tableModel;
    private final ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel;

    private final displayPanel;

    public TablePane() {
        //removed code for reading purposes
    }

    //IDE says issue with thinking displayPanel may have already been initialized
    public TablePane(JPanel panel) {
        //this();
        //displayPanel = panel;
    }


    //ListSelectionListener uses panel.add(jlabel)

}
```

Is it as simple as taking `final` off?

Comment: this question is too broad. please refine and ask a more specific question.

Comment: create reference on this JPanel from SwingTesting in your TablePane class (contructor will have one parameter) and in SwingTesting create getter on your JPanel.

Comment: @Sajmon Thank you for the reply, I was thinking that was the way I'd have to do it. Was hoping there were also alternative ways as well.

Comment: @WilliamShatner np, maybe are but now i dont know some different way and i think this technique use many developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `JLabel` object to the `TablePane` object (in `TablePane`'s constructor or by providing a custom `setLabel()` method).  Then you can use `StringBuilder` to create the text that needs to go on the label, and call `setText()` on the label with the constent of the `StringBuilder` object (via its `toString()` method).

I believe you are printing everytihn twice because the `valueChanged` method is called twice: once on the notification for the deselection of the current row, then again on the notification on the selection of the new row.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I have to pass the component via the constructor. Out of sheer curiosity, is there another way to do it? Any type of events or anything? Also, thank you for explaining the issue with `valueChanged`

Comment: You dont _have_ to pass it via the constructor (you can do so via any other ordinary function call as well), but you need to have a reference of the label before you can update it.  There are many ways to communicate data between objects; in this case passing the label object to where you handle the change event is the easiest solution.

Comment: I have added an edit, would you mind telling me what I need to do to fix that last issue at hand? (I know I already awarded the correct answer to you, but didn't expect I would have an issue with the constructor). I didn't think about the previous constructor being used elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, removing `final` will fix it.  The problem is that `final` declares the variable (more precisely the reference) unchangeable, so when you are calling `this();` it already assigns a value to `displayPanel`, so you cannot assign another value.  So either remove the `final` modifier, or create an initialization method that does the assignment except for `displayPanel` (which you will do separately in the second constructor), then call the initialization method from both constructor